# How to realize the communication between onHeadersReceived, onBeforeSendHeaders and onAuthRequired

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to implement an extension that will allow user to be on the same site 
under two different accounts in two different tabs within the same copy of the Chrome browser.

Now my code works so that onBeforeSendHeaders is invoked first and only then is invoked onHeadersReceived and my code is working incorrectly now. How can I use onAuthRequired to handle the call order? I need to invoke onHeadersReceived at first and then onBeforeSendHeaders.

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details) {

var detResp = details.responseHeaders;
    tabId = localStorage.getItem('tabName'),
    userVal = localStorage.getItem('userVal'),
    state = localStorage.getItem('currentState');

    console.log("1");//it's started second

if(typeof localStorage[userVal] === 'undefined') { 
    user = {};
    user["tabs"] = {};
}else{
    user = JSON.parse(localStorage[userVal]);
}

if (state) {
    localStorage.setItem('currentState', false);

    detResp.forEach(function(item, i, detResp) {

        if (item.name === 'set-cookie') {
            var cook = getCookieFromSetCookie(item.value);
            if (cook && userVal){
                user["tabs"]["tab"] = tabId;
                user[userVal] = {"name": cook["name"], "value": cook["value"]};
            }
        } 
    });
}
localStorage[userVal] = JSON.stringify(user);
```

}, {urls: [""]}, ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]);

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details) {
var detReq = details.requestHeaders,
    tabId = details.tabId,
    userVal = localStorage.getItem('userVal');

   console.log("2");//it's started first

if (typeof localStorage[userVal] != 'undefined'){

    JSON.parse(localStorage[userVal]);
    var userTab = user["tabs"]["tab"];

    if(userTab && userVal) {

        detReq.forEach(function(item, i, detReq) {
            if (item.name === 'Cookie') {
                item.value = concatCookie(user[userVal]);       
            }
        });
    }
}

return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
```

}, {urls: [""]}, ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);

Comment: Am I right to use onAuthRequired in such situation?

Comment: The headers of a **request** are sent first (onBeforeSendHeaders), then the **response's** headers are received (onHeadersReceived), so this order can't be reversed.

Comment: The problem is that when I log into account, choose user #1 clicking by link in popup (extension), the cookies saved in LocalStorage, then I update the page and the cookies are updated too, but they must be substituted from LocalStorage. Can you suggest a way in this situation? I need to change my code? Or somehow to handle it through onAuthRequired?

Comment: Maybe I need to use another event?